# Azure cloud service worker role profiling not loading symbols in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, azure, profiling, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to profile a worker role instance in my azure deployment using Visual Studio IDE, as I have some performance issues and I want to see which methods are taking a long time.

I am using Azure sdk v2.2, Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate on Windows 8.1.

I have deployed a profiling version of the service using a release build, and with 'Instrumentation' as the profiling method.

I have tried setting the Visual Studio Symbol file locations to none, the location of the .pdb files in the solution and the location of another folder with the .pdb files copied into it.

When I use the profiling report option in Visual Studio Server Explorer, the .vsp file downloads, but I see lots of the following entries in the output window;

```
Warning VSP2701: F:\approot\myapp.myname.Shared.dll could not be found when looking for symbol information.
```

Also, the output window includes the following;

```
VSP2340: Environment variables were not properly set during profiling run and managed symbols may not resolve.  Please use vsperfclrenv before profiling.
```

None of my own dll's or the system dll's are found, so no symbols are loaded.

The report is useless as it only shows hex values for the names instead of the actual method names.

I have read all the blogs, web entries and azure help pages on how to profile, and have followed each of the steps individually and together and I still cannot get the module and function names to resolve.

I have seen other questions similar to mine, but with no answer that solves the issue.

So, my question is, what else do I have to do to profile the azure worker role in Visual Studio?

Sub question: What is vsperfclrenv and how is that relevant (if at all) to the problem? (And how and where is it used if it is relevant?)

Thanks in advance for your help.